# How do I error handle the FTP functions in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling, ftp

When connecting to mysql, I have functions to get the relevant error message and error code, I see nothing of the sort in the list of ftp functions of PHP.
Is there a best practice to handle errors in FTP?

EDIT+CLARIFICATION: I think the best error messages are the system error messages + my own, is there a way to catch the system error messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [`error_get_last()`](http://php.net/error_get_last) for PHP >= 5.2 or [`$php_errmsg`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.phperrormsg.php) for older versions as detailed at the linked pages

Answer (score 0):

Looks like most of the ftp functions just return a true or false status. Some trigger a warning.

So the option you probably have is to check return status and have a meaningful error log for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the values returned by the functions. Usually it will return something like true (success) and false (fail). For instance, take `ftp_fget`. [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fget.php) says:

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on
>   failure.

Comment: The problem is I don't just want to know that the ftp attempt failed, I'd like some information on why it failed.  did it fail because the server was unreachable?  Couldn't login?  File not Found?  No Permissions?   that true/false return doesn't tell me any of that.