# ftp connection not working in browser but in cli

Tags: php, networking, ftp, command-line-interface

I am using this script to connect remote ftp site.

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect('test.com') or die("Couldn't connect to test.com");
```

this code working in command line, but while running from browser, its die and gives error.

Comment: so, whats the error it gives ?

Comment: Couldn't connect to test.com

Comment: Not your custom error. What error does `ftp_connect` give?

Comment: its blank... if use var_dump() > bool(false)

Comment: Then you have PHP warnings/errors disabled. Enable them. You cannot do any serious development without access to debugging information. Or use `error_get_last`.

Comment: Try to print the error. See following post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827089/how-do-i-error-handle-the-ftp-functions-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827089/how-do-i-error-handle-the-ftp-functions-in-php)

Comment: @CoenDamen read this thread, but no use full information. maybe my firewall blocking the out going php connection.

Comment: try to do a file_get_contents("test.com") to see if you can connect at all.

Comment: @CoenDamen  echo file_get_contents("http://google.com"); works okay

Comment: What is *"no use full information"*? What information did you get? + What about `fsockopen("test.com", 21)`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to test.com:21 (Permission denied)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not about code, but rather connectivity to a server. That’s especially true here since it works in code, but not via a web browser. This would likely be a more appropriate question for the [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) community.

Answer (score 0):

Your web server does not have a network connectivity to the FTP server `test.com`.

You need to talk to the server administrator or your hosting provider.

Comment: its working from command line, even if we call php script from command line its works. but not in web browser.

Comment: From what commandline? On the web server machine? Or local machine?

Comment: on centos webserver.

Comment: But still, your web server (the software, if not the machine) does not allow the connection.

Comment: only apache not allowed the connection. php working okay in cli

Comment: That's what I wrote, Apache = the web server software.